# function execute issue in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Dear friends this is my React Native According :

```
 renderAccordionContentBasic() {
        const { selectedItem } = this.state;
        return <View>

            <View style={Styles.formPicker}>                
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.gender}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ gender: itemValue })}  style={Styles.pickerText}>                    
                    <Picker.Item label="مرد" value="true" style={Styles.pickerText} />
                    <Picker.Item label="زن" value="false"  style={Styles.pickerText} />
                </Picker>
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.col}>
                <TextInput onChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ bankName: itemValue })} value={this.state.bankName} style={Styles.textInputHalf} placeholder={'نام بانک'} />
                <TextInput onChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ bankSheba: itemValue })} value={this.state.bankSheba} style={Styles.textInputHalf} placeholder={'شماره 16 رقمی شبای بانکی'} />
            </View>
            <TextInput style={Styles.textInputMulti} value={this.state.aboutus} onChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ aboutus: itemValue })} multiline={true} numberOfLines={10} placeholder={'رزومه و سوابق'} />

            <Button style={Styles.btn} **onPress={this.handleBasic(1)}**>
                <Text style={Styles.formBtnText}>{'ذخیره'.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                <Icon active name='content-save' type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={Styles.formBtnIcon} />
            </Button>
        </View>
    }
```

and this is my function for execute in button press :

```
handleBasic =(id)=>{
        alert(id)

    }
```

Now when my form ( component ) mount handleBasic() execute but when i press button handleBasic() did not execute
Please Help Me

Comment: Why is `onPress` wrapped in `**`?

Comment: i clear ** behind onPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `onPress` to be this

```
onPress={() => this.handleBasic(1)}
```

By calling like this `onPress={this.handleBasic(1)}`, The handle method will be called immediately when the component is rendered. So, it will not be called when you press the button.

Also, don't forget to bind your `renderAccordionContentBasic()` to your class. You can do it by use arrow function or `.bind(this)`.

Comment: If my answer can fix your problem, please mask this answer as correct answer to help others found this solution more easier.